# Router not allowed by landlord

Tags: router, subnet

I moved in to a student apartment building in Germany, and one of the rules on the list is that I cannot plug in a router to the network ports in the wall.

I asked about this rule, and apparently it's a serious one (they threatened to kick me out if I plug in my router).  Their reasoning is that it "will slow the internet down for everyone else" and it will generate "IP conflicts."

**Is it possible that's true?  If so, how?** I'm not sure how their network configuration works.  It looks like my wall network plug goes to another router, because my router's IP is 192.168.178.90, but my router's network assigns IPs in the 10.0.0s.

If it's not true and my router will not affect other people, is it possible for someone to detect that I have a router plugged in to theirs, and is there a way for me to hide that?

Comment: I know that a lot of apartment complexes incorporate that rule so their renters don't set up their own private streaming web sites. That would hog bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Slow down the internet" and "generate IP conflicts", NO. A router itself generates almost no traffic on it's own. And it will get an address via DHCP just like any other device.

**HOWEVER**, that doesn't mean the complex does not have valid reasons for restricting what you attach to their network. Generally, when one says "router" they mean a wireless access point. Having dozens of APs in close proximity just makes a huge mess -- yes, that *will* "slow down the internet", 'tho that's a gross mischaracterization of what's happening.

Can they tell? Of course. There are a lot of ways to determine what's connected to a port. Not the least of which is *entering the room and looking*. And that is ultimately the end of it -- it's hard to hide what's hanging off the end of a physical cable. (and we aren't here to help anyone circumvent the rules set by those who run their network.)

Comment: Thank you.  Assuming that nobody will physically see a router hypothetically plugged in to the wall, and I am not attempting to circumvent any rules, just curious about this in theory, are there ways to ensure that a router plugged in to another router is not identified as such?

Comment: You've already shown your hand; we know exactly why you're asking, so there will be no discussion of cloaking routers here.

Comment: That's a bit ridiculous.  This is a question and answer site—are you saying that from now on any question on cloaking routers will not be allowed, because I came in and said I want to break someone's rules?

Comment: It's okay; I got my answer.  Fine line though—I could've just asked if it's possible that plugging a router into another router will affect other peoples' network speed or something, and eliminated the whole residential thing.  Question would've been the same but on topic.  Rules are silly sometimes.